# ADF v2 Ensure that daily job will run after hourly (24 hours) job is successful

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way, where we can ensure in ADF v2 that my daily jobs will only run if the dependent hourly (24 hours) job is successful.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirements,you could consider below solution:

1.Run the hourly pipeline regularly and get the execution result of the pipeline output.

2.Log the results into a blob file,excluding the timestamp and execution status(success or fail)

3.Before your daily activity,please add a [look-up activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to retrieve the log info.Then use [For-Each activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) to loop the info.Inside the For-Each activity,use [if-condition activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) to check the hourly pipeline execution result.From this, you can judge the following logical operations.

Comment: This is so easy in ADF v1, weird that v2 is actually making such simple scenarios so difficult, version 2 is supposed to be generalized super set of version 1 but it's actually going backwards in functionality